# Generating a text file automatically using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to execute a Stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 and store the data in a text file. How to do this and how to generate a text file **automatically** with data in SQL Server 2008?

Comment: I would recommend checking out this link: http://thiagsundar.wordpress.com/export-data-to-text-file/ It shows a great way to export data to a text file from SQL Server.

Comment: Any language being used like c# ?

Answer (score 1):

One of the method is to make use of BCP (Bulk Copy Program) to do this. You need to have xp_cmdshell enabled to get this working.

Also you can also make use of SSIS Import/Export wizard to achieve this.

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'BCP "exec dbname.schemaname.procname" queryout "C:\outputfile.txt" -T -c -t,'
```

Check out these:

1. [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)
2. [SSIS](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/23/ssis-exporting-data-to-a-text-file-using-a-package/)